# how to use onclicklistener for grid view

Tags: java, android, xml

i used  gridview to display numbers, 
so if i click on any number the next activity should start. 
i tried this code but the app crashes

```
         private GridView gridView = null;

      gridView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()

    {
              public void onClick(View v5) 

        {
            setContentView(R.layout.Abc);
            Intent myIntent = new 

 Intent(getApplicationContext(),Abc.class);
            startActivity(myIntent);

        }
    });
```

here is the xml code for gridview

```
     <GridView
    android:id="@+id/month_gridView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/calendar_days"
    android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:background="@color/grid_background"
    android:fadingEdge="none"
    android:gravity="top|left"
    android:horizontalSpacing="2dp"
    android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
    android:numColumns="7"
    android:padding="1dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:verticalSpacing="2dp">
</GridView>
```

logcat
file log

```
 02-04 00:10:50.603: D/AndroidRuntime(341): Shutting down VM
    02-04 00:10:50.603: W/dalvikvm(341): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaughtexception(group=0x40015560)
    02-04 00:10:50.635: E/AndroidRuntime(341): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    02-04 00:10:50.635: E/AndroidRuntime(341): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.indianic.demo.calendark/com.indianic.demo.calendark.CalendarActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Don't call setOnClickListener for an AdapterView. You probably want setOnItemClickListener instead
    02-04 00:10:50.635: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
    02-04 00:10:50.635: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
    02-04 00:10:50.635: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
    02-04 00:10:50.635: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
    02-04 00:10:50.635: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    02-04 00:10:50.635: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    02-04 00:10:50.635: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
    02-04 00:10:50.635: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    02-04 00:10:50.635: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    02-04 00:10:50.635: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
    02-04 00:10:50.635: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
    02-04 00:10:50.635: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    02-04 00:10:50.635: E/AndroidRuntime(341): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Don't call setOnClickListener for an AdapterView. You probably want setOnItemClickListener instead
    02-04 00:10:50.635: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at android.widget.AdapterView.setOnClickListener(AdapterView.java:750)
    02-04 00:10:50.635: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at com.indianic.demo.calendark.CalendarActivity.onCreate(CalendarActivity.java:126)
    02-04 00:10:50.635: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
    02-04 00:10:50.635: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
    02-04 00:10:50.635: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  ... 11 more
    02-04 00:10:53.203: I/Process(341): Sending signal. PID: 341 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Updated the answer checkout!

Answer (score 43, accepted):

GridView is Like a ListView

You should use some thing like this

```
gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                int position, long id) {

            // DO something

        }
    });
```

the code is not perfect

for reference see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html

Answer (score 4):

You should use onItemClickListener instead of onClickListener.

Comment: Yes, just like QAMAR just wrote.

Comment: Almost correct:  `gridView.setOnItemClickListener` not `.onItemClickListener`. And `new OnItemClickListener` not `new onItemClickListener`.

Answer (score 1):

gridView.onClickListener() would be the listener for the grid as a view. gridView.setOnItemClickListener() would be the listener for an item in the grid. It would take the position as a parameter that would indicate the item you are clicking on. The parent parameter would indicate the gridView itself. You could use this to base the dimension of the item. Something like

```
view.setMinHeight(parent.getHeight()/n);
```

Comment: gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
  {
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                 int position, long id) {
    setContentView(R.layout.abc);
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Abc.class);
    startActivity(myIntent);
    //finish();
   }
  });

Answer (score 0):

```
 gridLayout_topCategory.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                 fragmentManager =getParentFragmentManager();
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new FragCategory(getContext(),fragmentManager),"fragCategory").addToBackStack(null).commit();
                Home.ll_bottomTabBarLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });
```