# How to use OnclickListener in GridView

Tags: java, android, asp.net, gridview

Here's the code. I want to open a new activity whenever I click on any one item in the Gridview. Please help. I know that we'll be going to use switch cases, but can't figure out how.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //set grid view item
    Bitmap homeIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.home);
    Bitmap userIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.personal);

    gridArray.add(new Item(homeIcon,"Home"));
    gridArray.add(new Item(userIcon,"User"));
    gridArray.add(new Item(homeIcon,"House"));
    gridArray.add(new Item(userIcon,"Friend"));
    gridArray.add(new Item(homeIcon,"Home"));
    gridArray.add(new Item(userIcon,"Personal"));
    gridArray.add(new Item(homeIcon,"Home"));
    gridArray.add(new Item(userIcon,"User"));
    gridArray.add(new Item(homeIcon,"Building"));
    gridArray.add(new Item(userIcon,"User"));
    gridArray.add(new Item(homeIcon,"Home"));
    gridArray.add(new Item(userIcon,"xyz"));


    gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1);
    customGridAdapter = new CustomGridViewAdapter(this, R.layout.row_grid, gridArray);
    gridView.setAdapter(customGridAdapter);
}
```

}

Comment: Already answered. read this https://stackoverflow.com/a/14675753/6266949

Comment: You should do research before asking a question

Comment: I have done research but I can't figure out how to edit the code to open new activity. Kindly please guide me correcting my code to open a new activity on every click. I know that we will going to use switch case, but can't figure out how...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define an intent

```
Intent intent;
```

Then define an item click listener for your GridView.

```
gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
            int position, long id) {

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                //Depending on the position, define your intent
                intent = new Intent(this, NewActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent)
                break;
            //further cases
        }

    }
});
```